# Dividend Discount Model - What is the cost of ordinary shares

Tags: finance

If the formula(s) is/are

Price = D (1+G) / R - G

Market Value of share = D/R

D = the dividend
R = return on equity
G = growth rate

nominal value £0.65
current market value ££67.31

current level of dividend is £0.61
grows at a compound rate of 8.9% per year

What is the cost of ordinary shares?

As you can see I dont have a return on equity, so ive tried using Market Value of share = D/R and flipping it to get R = D/Market Value of share.

My answers are somtimes in the negative or too low.

Answer (score 0):

All calculations are per share basis

Dividend Yield Approach:

Cost of Ordinary Share $= \frac{D_0(1+g)}{MV} + g$

Cost of Ordinary Share $= \frac{0.61(1+0.089)}{67.31} + 0.089$

Cost of Ordinary Share $ = 0.0988691$

Comment: If I was to calculate the WACC, then could I use that information to calculate the ordinary shares using the Dividend Valuation Model?

Comment: You need cost of debt and and debt to equity ration to complete the calculation of WACC\

Comment: Which I dont have. Very difficult assignment!